# Confused xcode? warning with suggested format fix, then next compile want to switch it back?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This is kinda bizarre for such a stalwart devtool like Xcode. But i have an NSLog as follows:

```
NSLog(@"getting request via remote notif.. with state: %d", application.applicationState);
```

and compiler warnings to change it to:

```
NSLog(@"getting request via remote notif.. with state: %ld", application.applicationState);
```

And on the very next compile, i get the exact same warnings but in reversed!

how odd..anyone know the real issue?

Comment: You need to use %ld but cast it to long. (long) before it.

Comment: It is not helping that you have not posted the exact warnings. The warnings did not change the code; you did.

Comment: Perhaps i wasn't clear enough, but it is exactly as i posted, the compiler directed me to make the above changes, then as soon as the changes were complete, and rebuilt, the compiler directed me to makes changes that brought me exactly back to my first efforts, and then the circle jerk begins. 

THAT is my question: does anyone know the issue behind this circular loop of warnings?

Comment: And does the Xcode project contain multiple targets, some of which are 32- and others 64-bit? This is the reason why the answer works as it forces the argument to `long` while using the `long` format specifier. The alternative is using conditional compilation which makes the code very messy.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't think so, but will double-check. Even if this was the cause, there is clearly a logic flaw in the error reconciliation process given that it creates an endless loop of suggestions. But.. it should not be 32 anywhere, so will make sure. ;)

Answer (score 2):

To support logging in a 64 bit environment, you should always use `%ld` and then cast your integer to `long` ie.

```
NSLog(@"blablabla with state: %ld", (long)application.applicationState);
```

See [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) for more info.

Comment: To each their own Duncan.. i luv it.. after spending far too long in Visual Studio, it is like a dream..

Comment: Given SO's penchant for staying on topic, politeness and respect, i am not sure why these comments are both relevant and not removed.

Comment: @drewatparseforumsdotcom.. Because of the way you wrote your question in the first place?-)